# Dreamweaver users? create list

Tags: list, dreamweaver

Okay... I'm a seasoned Dreamweaver user but I often code in Sublime text.

Anyway, you would think that if you have twenty lines of text, with line breaks (in code view) and you highlight all the lines and click the create unordered list button in properties, that it would make li's out of them. Dreamweaver throws all the lines of text into a single li.

There has to be a better way than cutting and pasting twenty open and close li tags, no?